# Table "jumps" when url is changed, angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with items. When a row is clicked, detailed item information shows upp in a fixed div next to the table.

The div next to the table is hooked up to a parameter in the url. So when I click an item, the url changes the url to /project/:itemID

The issue is that when a row is clicked, the table "jumps" to another position. The scroll changes position. I want it to stay the same place.

This is my controller which changes the url:

```
  $scope.goToProduct = function(id){
    var path = $location.path();
    var splitUrl = path.split('/');
    var project = splitUrl[1];
    console.log(project);
    $location.path(project + '/' + id);
  }
```

This is my view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Namn</th>
      <th>Manufactor</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:query" ng-click="goToProduct(product.pr_id)">
      <td>{{product.pr_usercode}}</td>
      <td>{{product.pr_title}}</td>
      <td>{{product.pr_producer}}</td>
      <td>{{product.pr_description}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you need the url to change? If not could you use ng-show on the detail element and then show that and retrieve the element details on click?

Comment: I want users to collaborate easily by sending links to each other. So yes, I need the url to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Ui-router had a handy directive. Just add autoscroll="false". Docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-autoscroll